# Parsing a text in Delphi

Tags: arrays, string, delphi, delphi-7

I have a textfile that has the following data:

```
dgm P1  
s0:->b1  
*s1:b2->b1  
S2:b2->b1,b3  
dgm P2  
s0:->b2  
*s1:b1,b3->b2
```

I want to parse this file to get an array whose element will contain each of the
dgm's till the next one. That is, the first element will be:

```
dgm P1  
s0:->b1  
*s1:b2->b1  
S2:b2->b1,b3
```

The second element will be:

```
dgm P2  
s0:->b2  
*s1:b1,b3->b2
```

etc.
Please how do i go about that in Delphi. I am looking for a better way to do this. I tried loading from the file to TStringList.

```
begin
str:=TstringList.Create;
try
str.LoadFromFile('example.txt');
for i:=0 to str.Count -1 do
if str[i] ='dgm' then
 //get the position, add it to an array;
 //get the next position, till the end;
 //use the positions to divide up the string

 finally
 str.Free;
```

However, this is not working and I also think there might be a better way
to handle this than I briefly outlined.

Comment: What does not working mean? You need to take the time to read [help] and [mcve].

Comment: `:=` is assignment. Use `=` for comparison. You might be better reading out the first 3 characters of comparing against `dgm`. What about case sensitivity? Whitespace? What are the rules of this language? Do you know? Do you know how to perform basic operations on strings? It looks like you don't. If you don't know then you are going to struggle.

Comment: It is not working because you check for 'dmg' string but the file has 'dmg P1', 'dmg P2', etc

And you need to replace := with =, as David points out

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I find that using AnsiContainsStr(str,'dgm') has helped me with the issue.

Comment: AnsiStartsStr would be better

Comment: what Delphi version do you use ?

Comment: You may be able to use RegEx to check for 'dmg' but not sure whether it adds any speed or value in your case

Comment: @JohnKouraklis spped most probably would be limited by HDD/network (file source) and value would only be added if he would need his users o be able to adapt to different file formats - but then it would be much more complex than simply replace one marker constant with another... There would be needed to add scripting or control flow graph, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AS. This answer uses features of Delphi 2010+ because it was written before the topicstarter specified his target Delphi version. Still this code can be the skeleton for his own implementation using libraries and language features he has available.

```
function ParseDgmStringsList( const str: TStrings ): TArray<TArray<String>>;
var
  s: string;
  section: TList<String>;
  receiver: TList<TArray<String>>;

  procedure FlushSection;
  begin
    if section.Count > 0 then begin
       receiver.Add( section.ToArray() );
       section.Clear;
    end;
  end;
begin
  section := nil;
  receiver := TList<TArray<String>>.Create;
  try
    section := TList<String>.Create;

    for s in str do begin
      if StartsText('dgm ', s) then // or StartsStr
         FlushSection;   
      section.Add( s );
    end;

    FlushSection;
    Result := receiver.ToArray();
  finally
    receiver.Destroy;
    section.Free;
  end;
end;
```

- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.StrUtils.StartsStr
- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.StrUtils.StartsText

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.Generics.Collections.TList_Properties

PS. Note that "using `AnsiContainsStr(str,'dgm')`" is fragile and hardly correct - it will generate false positive at lines like `S2:b2->bcdgmaz,b3`.
You should check that `dgm` starts the string and that it is a separate word rather than part of some random longer word (in other words search for `'dgm' + #32` instead of mere `'dgm'`

PPS. Another thing to consider is how would you handle files that starts with non-dgm lines? What would you do with empty lines, indented lines? For example how would you parse the file like that?

```
s8:->b2  
;*s1:b1,b3->b2
dgm P1  
s0:->b1  
*s1:b2->b1  

S2:b2->b1,b3  
    dgm P2  
  s0:->b2  
*s1:b1,b3->b2
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! The data in the file are actually structured exactly as I presented, else an error is thrown signifying bad input. Your answer goes beyond that, but I'm glad to accept it.

Comment: @Emeka if `else an error is thrown signifying bad input` then I think exactly you should extend the parser I drafted above so it would explicitly accommodate or fail on any possible irregularity. For example using case-ignoring StartsText accommodates for case irregularities. You may add `Trim` or `TrimLeft` calls, etc. Also I assume that `dgm` is followed by space char, but perhaps it also would be valid if followed by tab ( #9 ) or some other delimiter, etc. Detecting separator line muight get realy complex, so you would better offload it to yet another function, however complex

Comment: Also, if your Delphi is modern enough consider dropping `TStringList` altogether. It gives some complex features, but it pays for it with relatively slow speed and relatively high memory consumption. If you only need to read the file and need none of those advanced services, then You can probably use simplistic (thus faster) array of string instead. Read about `System.IOUtils.TFile.GetAllLines(filename, TEncoding): TStringDynArray`. Additionalyl you would not have to care about destroying TStringList object :-)

Comment: As a rule of thumb - always specify Delphi version in the tags under your question, because that greatly influences which language/libraries features are available for you, for example there were significant chances my draft would not even compile for you if you would have Delphi 2007 or before. And in Delphi 2009 it would compile but then destroy all your data...

Comment: I'm using Delphi 7. Is that modern enough? Alright, noted!

Comment: No, Delphi 7 would not have `TArray<x>` and `TList<x>` and you would have to adapt my code to the library features you do have.  PS. Personally in this year i'd try to upgrade from Delphi 7 to CodeTyphon/Lazarus